# Regex matching a text after a specific string until another specific string

Tags: regex, python-3.5

If I have the following example:

```
X-FileName: pallen (Non-Privileged).pst

Here is our forecast

 Message-ID: <15464986.1075855378456.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
```

How can I select the text

```
Here is our forecast
```

after "X-FileName .... \n" until "Message-ID" execluded?

I read about lookahead and behind and tried this but didn't work:

```
(?<=X-FileName:(\n)+$).+(?=Message-ID:)
```

Comment: You may use `s.split("\n\n")[1]`. Or `re.search(r'X-FileName:.*[\r\n]+(.+)', s).group(1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there anything wrong with the second one?

Comment: I don't know about Python, but in most languages the `$` above would refer to the end of the whole string, not the end of the lookbehind. And in fact you wouldn't even be allowed to do a lookbehind where the length of the lookbehind string isn't known at compile time (which it isn't in this case because of the `+`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

`(?:X-FileName:[^\n]+)\n+([^\n]+)\n+(?:Message-ID:)` (group #1 is the match)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LkgKH/2)

Explanation:

`(?:X-FileName:[^\n]+)` matches `X-Filename:` followed by any number of characters that aren't newlines, without capturing it (`?:`).

`\n+` matches any number of consecutive newlines.

`([^\n]+)` matches and captures any number of consecutive characters that aren't newlines.

`\n+`, again, matches any number of consecutive newlines.

`(?:Message-ID:)` matches `Message-ID:` without capturing it (`?:`).

**Edit**: as @WiktorStribiżew mentioned though, splitting your text into lines may be an easier/cleaner way to retrieve what you want.

Comment: The line contains X=Filename and Message-ID are excluded.

Comment: Group #1 contains exactly "Here is our forecast" (in green on the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LkgKH/2)). Isn't it what you requested?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches here, and they depend on the broader context. If your expected substring is the second paragraph, just split with `\n\n` (or `\r\n\r\n`) and get the second item from the resulting list.

If it is a text inside some larger text, use a regex.

See a Python demo:

```
import re
s='''X-FileName: pallen (Non-Privileged).pst

Here is our forecast

Message-ID: <15464986.1075855378456.JavaMail.evans@thyme>'''
# Non-regex way for the string in the exact same format
print(s.split('\n\n')[1])
# Regex way to get some substring in a known context
m = re.search(r'X-FileName:.*[\r\n]+(.+)', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

The regex means:

- `X-FileName:` - a literal substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `[\r\n]+` - 1 or more CR or LF chars
- `(.+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SgZ8K2/1).